# Test conditional rendering of components based on ContextAPI data using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to do unit testing on the Form component. `user` is context data that is shared with all the children component.

```
 const { user } = useContext(UserContextAPI);
 return (
  <> {!user ? (
        <>
          {navigation.push({
            pathname: "./Login",
            state: { editProduct: "edit" },
          })}
        </>
      ) : (
        <Form>.....</From>
      )
  }
 </>
);
```

I have written a simple test case to test form component

```
 it("should contain From component", () => {
   let wrapper = mount(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <EditProduct.WrappedComponent />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
    expect(wrapper.find("Form").exist()).toEqual(true);
  });
```

But the test case failed I think based on conditional rendering it doesn't go to test the Form component. How could we do the conditional rendering based on the context data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add context provider at the top level:

```
it("should contain From component", () => {
    const UserContextAPI = React.createContext({});

    let wrapper = mount(
        <UserContextAPI.Provider value="{}">
            <BrowserRouter>
                <EditProduct.WrappedComponent />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </UserContextAPI.Provider>
    );
    expect(wrapper.find("Form").exist()).toEqual(true);
});
```

Comment: value should be empty? why? In my case value is an object. `value={{}}` This contains state value and setstate function. I want to pass now only state value. Is that possible?

Comment: @Subrato Patnaik value in the code just example. You can set whatever you need for you test purposes.

Comment: Could i even pass state `user`?

Comment: one more help from you I want to pass `location.state`  to EditProduct component. How could I do that?

Comment: @Subrato Patanik you can use `useLocation()` hook of React Router to get location object.

Answer (score 1):

I did this way and It worked. @Ken Bekov Credits to you

```
it("should contain From component", () => {
   const history = createBrowserHistory();
    const state = { pid: 1 };
    history.push("/EditProduct", state);
    wrapper = mount(
      <UserContextAPI.Provider value={{ user: 1 }}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <EditProduct.WrappedComponent />
        </Router>
      </UserContextAPI.Provider>
    );
    expect(wrapper.find("Form").exist()).toEqual(true);
});
```